# c# programatically exporting transport rule - exchange 2010

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to export transport rule programmatically.

My code works for simple commands like get-exchangeserver and get-TransportRule but if I try to give command importing rules to some file it gives error that the given command is not recognized as cmdlet, script.

My code is as below (I have tried giving both windows authentication or user's authentication who is exchange admin):

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(serverUri, SHELL_URI, creds);
try
{
    using (Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
    {
        PowerShell psh = PowerShell.Create();
        psh.Runspace = rs;
        rs.Open();
        psh.AddCommand("$file = Export-TransportRuleCollection -ExportLegacyRules" +"Set-Content -Path " + @"C:\LegacyRules3.xml" + "-Value file.FileData -Encoding Byte");
        psh.Invoke();
```

I am using C# and Exchange Server 2010, PowerShell version is 1.0. The remote OS is Winodws 7.

Any idea what correction I should do?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on Export-TransportRuleCollection:

In Exchange 2010, you must export the rules collection to a variable and then use the Set-Content cmdlet to write the data to an XML file. For more information, see Set-Content.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124410(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: Hi,                                                            Thanks for the reply, if you see my code I am already using the cmdlet but not able to make it work through the coding, would like to know how I can split the command to make it work through the c# code.                                                        Regards,                                                             Amit

Comment: Are you sure the credentials you're using belong to the Exchange RBAC groups that has the necessary permissions to do that?  If they don't Exchange will not give them that cmdlet to use in the session.

Comment: It looks like you're connecting to an Exchange remoting session for this.  That's a constrained, no-language session that doesn't have access to the filesystem on the Exchange server.  Normally to use these sessions you create a local session, then connect to and import the remote session functions into that local session (implicit remoting).

Comment: Hi, Got the problem resolved after using New-PSSession and able to call the script remotely, thanks for the help.